# Xamarin.Android & Azure Push Notifications Internal Server Error

Tags: azure, xamarin.android, google-cloud-messaging, azure-mobile-services

I'm following the guide at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-android-get-started-push (as well as the original Xamarin one that this appears to have cribbed from), but I'm running into a problem registering my client.

I am successfully logging a user in prior to setting up the push notification service.

Both `GcmClient.CheckDevice(...)` and `GcmClient.CheckManifest(...)` succeed, and my PushHandlerService is being called.

Push.RegisterAsync(...) in my PushHandlerService is throwing a MobileServiceInvalidOperationException because it received an HTTP 500 Internal Server Error from the service.

Looking at FREB logs, it appears that the "error" is actually supposed to be a success, and interestingly is somehow related to the EasyAuthModule:

95. NOTIFY_MODULE_COMPLETION    ModuleName="EasyAuthModule_64bit", Notification="AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST", fIsPostNotificationEvent="true", CompletionBytes="297", ErrorCode=**"The operation completed successfully.
    (0x0)"**   05:51:01.092
96. Module_set_response_error_status
    Warning ModuleName="EasyAuthModule_64bit", Notification="AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST", **HttpStatus="500", HttpReason="Internal Server Error", HttpSubStatus="79", ErrorCode="Unspecified error
    (0x80004005)"**, ConfigExceptionInfo=""    05:51:01.092
97. NOTIFY_MODULE_COMPLETION    ModuleName="EasyAuthModule_64bit", Notification="AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST", fIsPostNotificationEvent="true", CompletionBytes="0", **ErrorCode="The operation completed successfully.
    (0x0)"**   05:51:01.092

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it the error is happening when you call `client.GetPush().RegisterAsync()`?  This is currently an issue and we are deploying a fix on the Azure side to fix this.  In the interim, you can see the fix for this here: https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter5/android/

Comment: That was exactly it, thanks!
Is there anywhere I can follow to know about the azure fix?

For any others who run into this problem, [this, from the same book](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter5/concepts/#registering-your-mobile-client) was what I needed. It's a new data contract and a regular InvokeAsync instead of the RegisterAsync call.

Comment: Nowhere you can follow.  However, we are rolling out the fix now and expect the fix to be globally available by 12/16.